# Over voltage on Arduino and Ardumoto

Tags: motor, arduino-leonardo, arduino-motor-shield

I am using Arduino Leonardo and [Ardumoto](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9815) to drive 2 12v motors running at 1.3 amps each.

I purchased a rechargeable battery of 12V with 5AH

I first started by plugging in the battery to the Arduino via the barrel jack. Arduino then sparks and is fried.

I read somewhere that I wasn't supposed to hook it up to the Arduino and to hook it up to the VIN ports in the Ardumoto. I purchased a new Arduino and plugged in the Positive and negative from the battery to the ports and now the Ardumoto board fried (copper lining on board burnt off).

I'm reading online and from what I've gathered, the Ardumoto can handle a max of 18 volts and a maximum of 2 amps per each output. I'm obviously missing something and would not like to fry my boards next time.

Please assist?

[image: hook up of ardumoto]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you got the polarity right?

Comment: Would you post a diagram (a photo of something hand drawn will be fine) and, maybe photos of your wiring?

Comment: Alright, I went ahead and edited the picture

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sure I had the correct polarity. If I didn't the first time you sure as heck know that I triple checked the second time.

Comment: @teknicalissue  You could add another image.  There are good photos of the Ardumoto on the web.  You could take one of them and point out exactly which copper trace have burned.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Done! It should be up now

Comment: Were the motors connected up at the time? Any chance of a short there?

Comment: That connector on the ardumoto is directly connected to VIN. And so is the barrel jack on the leonardo. The only reason it is preferred to use the vin on the ardumoto, is that the vin trace on the arduino board is not made for 4 amps. But in both cases nothing should have blown up like it did. You can maybe still fix the board by soldering a wire between the vin header just next to the screw terminal, and the vin-pin that goes down into the arduino. That way you bypass the blown trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, everything *should* be wired correctly. It should not have failed.

Unfortunately, testing this sort of thing with a 5 amp-hour lead-acid battery is not a great way to get started, since a battery that large can source a *lot* of current, and doing anything wrong will likely produce immediate and spectacular failure.

Really, the only think I can think of is that you have the polarity of the output lugs/pins on the battery backwards. Buy a $5 multimeter, and check them.